# MvcSiteMap Persistent BreadCrumb Navigation With a Search Criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm currently at a loss as to how to complete this functionality..

Right now we have a view containing a kendo grid and a kendo tabstrip which contains partial views for each tab. On the left side of the view we have a sidebar that contains navigation to different pages as well as a search criteria for searching people (first name, last name, etc).

The kendo grid is populated by a search criteria. From this page we navigate to another view. When trying to use breadcrumb navigation back to the original page the search criteria is lost and the kendo grid is populated with all of the entries from the database.

Below are the signatures for populating the grid by the search criteria and generating the view respectively:

```
public JsonResult searchPerson([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
                string LastName = null, string FirstName = null, string JurorNr = null,
                int JuryYear = 0)
{
    //Code
}

public ActionResult firstSearch(PersonSearchCriteria personSearchCriteria)
{
    //Return View
}
```

I would like to avoid making any major signature changes to the existing code. I initially thought of just saving the search criteria as hidden variables and persisting them on the page navigation, however I realized there'd be a lot more parameters to take into account (page number of the grid, any filtering/sorting on the grid, page size of the grid, person selection, etc).

Is there a way that I can persist multiple objects across page requests through breadcrumbs (a DataSourceRequest object, and a SearchCriteria object)?
Any help figuring out this navigation would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you figure out the solution? i am facing the same issue.